# load() not accepting a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, load

Can't you use a variable in a load() command?

In my AJAX Script :

```
 var $self = $(this); 

 var uniqueID = $self.data('id'); //getting ID dynamically (e.g 256)

 var myclass = ".likes-"+uniqueID;
```

Then in the success callback :

```
 alert(myclass);
```

Returns as expected :

```
 .likes-256
```

But the following in the success callback :

```
 $(myclass).load(location.href + myclass);
```

Doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are loading `http://www.example.com/.likes-256`

Comment: I know what the issue was... just giving debugging hints

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ok I see where I was going wrong.

This is the correct way to do it :

```
 $(".likes-"+uniqueID).load(location.href + " .likes-"+uniqueID);
```